# migx TV (MODx REVO) - date format

Tags: date, date-format, modx, modx-revolution, migx

I have a problem: I cannot bring **date without time through MIGX TV**
created by TV type migx:

```
{«Field»: «Date», «caption»: «Date», «inputTVtype»: «date»}
```

I deduce that everything appears normal by  this way `[[+ date]]`, but it is **displayed as date and time** and I want to display **only the date part**!

I tried this `[[+ date: date ="% Y-% m-% d"]]` but instead of the correct date `1/1/1970` is displayed.

I understand that the problem is that I use the TV type migx, but I need to use migx because there can be lots of dates!

Help me, please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Input+and+Output+Filters+%28Output+Modifiers%29 - you need `:strtotime` modificator before `:date` -

```
[[+mydate:strtotime:date=`%Y-%m-%d`]]
```